# php function to mysqli update

Tags: php, mysqli, crud

Trying to create a function that would be used to update any row of any table, but I'm getting trouble getting into it.

Data sent in array where the array index is the field name in table and the value is the new value for that index.

For examplpe:

```
$args["name"] = "NewName";
$args["city"] = "NewCity";
$args["id"] = 4; // row ID to update
```

What I got:

```
function create_update_query($table, $keys){
    $keys = array_map('escape_mysql_identifier', $keys);
    $table = escape_mysql_identifier($table);
    $updates = "";
    $count = 0;
    foreach($keys as $index => $value){
        if($index != "id"){
            $count++;
            if($count == count($keys)-1){
                $updates = $updates . "$index = ?";
            }else{
                $updates = $updates . "$index = ?,";
            }
        }
    }    
    return "UPDATE $table SET $updates WHERE id = ? LIMIT 1";
}
```

After that, I have the function to really do the query:

```
function crud_update($conn, $table, $data){
    $sql = create_update_query($table, array_keys($data));
    if(prepared_query($conn, $sql, array_values($data))){
        $errors [] = "OK";
    }else{
        $errors [] = "Something weird happened...";
    }
}
```

The function that makes the prepared statement itself:

```
function prepared_query($mysqli, $sql, $params, $types = ""){
    $types = $types ?: str_repeat("s", count($params));
    if($stmt = $mysqli->prepare($sql)) { 
        $stmt->bind_param($types, ...$params);
        $stmt->execute();
        return $stmt;
    } else {
        $error = $mysqli->errno . ' ' . $mysqli->error;
        echo "<br/>".$error; 
    }
}
```

When trying to submit the data with the following criteria:

```
$args['name'] = "Novo Nome";
$args['field'] = "New Field";
$args['numaro'] = 10101010;
$args['id'] = 4;

//create_update_query("teste_table", $args);
crud_update($link, "teste_table", $args);
```

Have an error:

```
1064 You have an error in your SQL syntax; check the manual that corresponds to your MySQL server version for the right syntax to use near '1 = ?,2 = ?,3 = ? WHERE id = ? LIMIT 1' at line 1
```

But if I echo the query created by `create_update_query` it seems ok:

```
UPDATE `teste_table` SET name = ?,field = ?,numaro = ? WHERE id = ? LIMIT 1
```

Any help would be appreciated.
Thanks.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The problem is that as you pass the keys to `create_update_query()` as

```
create_update_query($table, array_keys($data));
```

Using `array_keys()` will just take the key names, so the `$keys` parameter is just a list of the field names as something like ...

```
Array(
 0=> 'name',
 1 =>'field',
 2 =>'numaro'
)
```

You then extract the data using

```
foreach($keys as $index => $value){
```

and build your SQL with

```
$updates = $updates . "$index = ?";
```

so at this point, the indexes are the numeric value, so change these lines to...

```
$updates = $updates . "$value = ?";
```

which is the name of the field.

With the various other changes, I would suggest the code should be...

```
foreach($keys as $value){
    if($value != "id"){
        $updates = $updates . "$index = ?,";
    }
}    
$updates = rtrim($updates, ",");
return "UPDATE $table SET $updates WHERE id = ? LIMIT 1";
```

Comment: But to create the query I want the key names as name, field and numaro. It seems when I use the data in the second function it translates to index. The change you provided doesnt work. Don't give any error but doesn't work.

Comment: No, it doesnt work. Doesn't show any error, but doesn't work.

Comment: Have you check the SQL that it is generating?

Comment: It's posted in the initial question I guess.

Comment: So the output using this code is posted in the original question?

Comment: Yes, it's in the original question.

Comment: The output with the modified code?!  How did you include the output before I'd even answered the question?

Comment: Sorry. I didn't see the new query properly. The query now is duplicated in the ID field. The id field is supposed to not be updated. I need to remove the last id =?, before WHERE but my code doesn't seems to work: Query -> UPDATE `teste_table` SET `field` = ?,`numaro` = ?,`id` = ? WHERE id = ? LIMIT 1 (change the if($index != "id") to ($value != "id") without luck.

Comment: Doesn't matter if it is updated, as it's part of the WHERE clause, it should just set it to the same value.

Comment: But it seems it doesnt work, because now I can't change the last update field name to = ?. Instead it shows as = ?, WHERE ... causing an mysql sintax error.

Comment: I need to remove the last update set id = ? before WHERE. Otherwhise I will get an error because I'm not providing the correct ammount of information to the information. And if I add another id into array. The code you provided creates the folowing SQL: UPDATE `teste_table` SET `name` = ?,`field` = ?,`numaro` = ?,`id` = ? WHERE id = ? LIMIT 1 . The problem is the IF that doesn't seems to do what should do...

Comment: Found the problem. My error. I have another function that adds ` ` between the field name. And of course "`id`" is != than "id".